# Python - Checking if the data in the files is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists where I have the same number of files. The files in both folders have the same names, for example:

```
Test1 folder:
files.txt
test.txt
name.txt
```

and so on.
In the test2 folder I have the same named files.
How can I compare for each file if the data in both files is the same? So whether:

```
test1 / files.txt = test2 / files.txt
test1 / test.txt = test2 / test.txt
test1 / name.txt = test2 / name.txt
```

```
import os
import difflib

test1_path = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test1"
test2_path = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test2"

if os.path.exists(test1_path):
    files_test1 = []
    for name in os.listdir(test1_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(test1_path, name)):
            files_test1.append(os.path.join(test1_path, name))

if os.path.exists(test2_path):
    files_test2 = []
    for name in os.listdir(test2_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(test2_path, name)):
            files_test2.append(os.path.join(test2_path, name))
```

Are you able to advise something?

Comment: What is your data? Text? Numbers?

Comment: if data are exactly the same then you can read as text and use `text1 == text2` but if there can be minimal difference like extra space or new line then it may not work. And it can't show you which lines are different.

Comment: if both folders have files with the same names then you could read names only from one folder and use them to create full paths in both folders. And there is no need to keep them on list but you could compare them directly in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to perform two loops.  One is enough.  Also you can use the `filecmp` package to compare file contents.

```py
import os
import filecmp  #  to compare files

test1_path = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test1'
test2_path = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test2'

if os.path.exists(test1_path) and os.path.exists(test2_path):
    all_same = True
    for name in os.listdir(test1_path):
        file1 = os.path.join(test1_path, name)
        file2 = os.path.join(test2_path, name)
        if (
                os.path.isfile(file1) and
                os.path.isfile(file2) and
                not filecmp.cmp(file1, file2)
        ):
            all_same = False
    print('all files are the same:', all_same)
```

Note that the code can be simplified if you know for sure that both directories contain the same file names.